# How can I add GUI with 4 images altogether with PIL in every round

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to add images of the 6 sides of the dice with tkinter and PIL module but I am not able to.
How can I do it? 4 images altogether with a button to roll the dice with 4 images. This is what I want.
Thank you for helping. I need it in every round for the match.
It is a game of dice for 4 player.

```
    import random
    
    def main():
        player1 = 0
        player1wins = 0
        player2 = 0
        player2wins = 0
        player3 = 0
        player3wins = 0
        player4 = 0
        player4wins = 0
        rounds = 1
    
        while rounds != 11:
            print("Round " + str(rounds))
            player1 = dice_roll()
            player2 = dice_roll()
            player3 = dice_roll()
            player4 = dice_roll()
            print("Player 1 Roll: " + str(player1))
            print("Player 2 Roll: " + str(player2))
            print("Player 3 Roll: " + str(player3))
            print("Player 4 Roll: " + str(player4))
    
            if((player1>player2 and player1>player3 and player1>player4) and (player1 != player2 and player1 != player3 and player1 != player4)):
                player1wins = player1wins + 1
                print("Player 1 wins!\n")
            elif((player2>player1 and player2>player3 and player2>player4) and (player2 != player1 and player2 != player3 and player2 != player3)):
                player2wins = player2wins + 1
                print("Player 2 wins!\n")
            elif((player3>player1 and player3>player2 and player3>player4) and (player3 != player1 and player3 != player2 and player3 != player4)):
                player3wins = player3wins + 1
                print("Player 3 wins!\n")
            elif((player4>player1 and player4>player2 and player4>player3) and (player4 != player1 and player4 != player2 and player4 != player3)):
                player4wins = player4wins + 1
                print("Player 4 wins!\n")
            else:
                print("Round Draw! \n")
    
            rounds = rounds + 1
    
        if((player1wins>player2wins and player1wins>player3wins and player1wins>player4wins) and (player1wins != player2wins and player1wins != player3wins and player1wins != player4wins)):
                print("Player 1 Wins The Match \n\nRounds Won: " + str(player1wins))
        elif((player2wins>player1wins and player2wins>player3wins and player2wins>player4wins) and (player2wins != player1wins and player2wins != player3wins and player2wins != player3wins)):
                print("Player 2 Wins \n\nRounds Won: " + str(player2wins))
        elif((player3wins>player1wins and player3wins>player2wins and player3wins>player4wins) and (player3wins != player1wins and player3wins != player2wins and player3wins != player4wins)):
                print("Player 3 Wins \n\nRounds Won: " + str(player3wins))
        elif((player4wins>player1wins and player4wins>player2wins and player4wins>player3wins) and (player4wins != player1wins and player4wins != player2wins and player4wins != player3wins)):
                print("Player 4 Wins \n\nRounds Won: " + str(player4wins))
        else:
                print("Match Draw!")
    
        def dice_roll():
        diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
        return diceRoll
    
        main()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code first.  Also there is no GUI code, you should post what you have tried on showing images.

Comment: what did you try ? What means `"I am not able to"` ? It is the most useless information. Did you get error message ? Then you should show it in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Did you have some problem to display it ? Then you should describe it with details and with code which makes this problem. But I don't see any `Label` with `PhotoImage` in your code. BTW: You have to know that there is **bug** in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when you assign it to local variable - you may see empty image. You have to assign `PhotoImage` to glocal variable or to other object.

Comment: see **Note** at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). It describe **bug** in `PhotoImage` and how to fix it.

Comment: BTW: if `player1 > player2` then automatically it is also `player1 != player2` and you don't have to check `player1 != player2`

Comment: instead of `player1`, `player2`, `player3`, `player4` you could use list `players = [0, 0, 0, 0]` and then you could use `for`-loop to run the same code for every player - ie. `for number, p in enumerata(players, 1): print("Player", number, "Roll:", p)` - and then code will be shorter and simpler. And the same with `player1wins`, `player2wins`, etc.

Comment: if you want to create GUI - with tkinter or other framework - then you will have to rewrite all code because GUIs works different then text programs - they have to run event loop all time to check if there is new key/mouse event and to update/redraw widgets in window. And running own loop `while rounds != 11:` will block event loop - and GUI will freeze. So you have to first learn how to GUI works and how to create programs with `tkinter` - and later you can try to use it with your game.